# How to fetch values from array in javascript +angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to get values from array index in javascript +angularjs like ng-repeat but in my controller

```
Array[0]
  0: Object
     class:"text-area"
     text: "Arif#2:hi bro"
     time_stamp: 1484644646user_
     chat_img: "images/noimage.jpg"
    __proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

Now i want to print class name like "class=text-area" and this will be a loop
Thanks

Here is my code

```
 $scope.p=get_chat_history(); this function give me array
 console.log('key',$scope.p);
```

Sorry fo all that i am very beginner 
I add some more detail

```
function get_chat_history() {
        var data = [];
        var time_stamp = '';
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.time_stamp = window.localStorage.getItem('time_stamp');

        }, 3000);
        console.log('time_stamp', $scope.time_stamp);
        if (!$scope.time_stamp) {
            $scope.time_stamp = Date.now();
        }
        $http({
            url: "https://testing.twodegrees.io/chat/history/" + my_chat_id + "/" + my_chat_friend_id + "/" + $scope.time_stamp,
            headers: {
                'X-TWO_DEGREE-APP_ID': 'test_Anonymous_786',
                'X-TWO_DEGREE-APP_TOKEN': actoken
            },
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function mySucces(success_res) {


            // console.log(' history data',success_res);
            var chat_images_images = [];
            for (var p = 0; p < success_res.data.chats.length; p++)
            {
                console.log('p', p);
                chat_images_images[p] = [];
                var message_body = success_res.data.chats[p].body;
                var myJSON = JSON.parse(message_body);
                var time_stamp = success_res.data.chats[p].time_stamp;
                var myJSON2 = JSON.parse(time_stamp);
                if (myJSON.sname == my_name) {
                    var class_name = 'text-area2';
                } else {
                    var class_name = 'text-area';
                }
                //console.log('time_stamp',myJSON2);
                if (p == 0) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem('time_stamp', myJSON2);
                }

                var newtest = {
                    text: myJSON.text,
                    class: class_name,
                    user_chat_img: "images/noimage.jpg",
                    time_stamp: myJSON2
                }
                // console.log('chat history',myJSON);
                data.push(newtest);

            }
            // console.log('chat history',data);

        });

        var urle = "https://testing.twodegrees.io/chat/history/" + my_chat_id + "/" + my_chat_friend_id + "/" + $scope.time_stamp;

        console.log('url history', urle);

        return data;

    }
```

this function send me a array and i want to use this

Comment: Can you post your code here, or a link to a jsfiddle/jsbin etc?

Comment: Provide us more details.... like what you want to achieve... with your tries

Comment: i get this in my view using a loop  ng-repeat but i want now to get this in my controller  in my view i get like this                                                     ng-repeat="message in mymessages"                                                              and then {{message.class}}

Comment: What do you want to get in your controller ?

Comment: If you will provide piece of code here we can help you better.

Comment: I want to add this text to another array

Comment: p=get_chat_history();//this function give me array 
  console.log('key',$scope.p);

Comment: `console.log($scope.p[0].class);`

Comment: i have already try this but not working

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Seems like you mess up with the async call and iterate over the array before the http promise is resolved. I am assuming here that your `get_chat_history` is an async (api) call.

Instead of `$scope.p = get_chat_history()` you should probably do something like this:

```
get_chat_history().then(function(response) {
    $scope.p = response;
    // now you can iterate over the array, because the http promise is resolved
    // see below function to do that
});
```

---

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate over the array and then over all of its values. You can do that by using [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach):

```
// Iterate over array
angular.forEach($scope.p, function(item) {
    // Iterate over object keys
    angular.forEach(item, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + "=" + value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it simple you can do it like

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.p.length; i++){
   console.log($scope.p[i].class);
   console.log($scope.p[i].text);
}
```

If this does not work in the controller you can try like

```
get_chat_history().then(function(res) {
    $scope.p = res;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.p.length; i++){
        console.log($scope.p[i].class);
        console.log($scope.p[i].text);
    }
}
```

Or

```
get_chat_history().then(function(res) {
    for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        console.log(res[i].class);
        console.log(res[i].text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working using ng-repeat in my view but not getting this in my controller

Comment: @NazarHussain I can make an educated guess that your `get_chat_history()` is an async function?